# How can i perform this loop thing in switch-case in C. I Want to print that the student got A grade if they enter obtained marks between 90 and 100

Tags: c, switch-statement

```
int user_marks;
printf("Enter your obatined marks to know your grade: ")
scanf("%d", &user_marks);

switch (user_marks)
{
case user_marks>=90 && user_marks<=100:
    printf("Your grade is A.");
    break;


default:
    printf("Enter valid marks.");
    break;
}
```

I want to print that the user got an A grade if they enter numbers between 90 and 100 including those values in the "case" section of the code.

Comment: You can't evaluate a `case` statement at run time. The complier must be able to resolve it. Use `if ... else`.

Comment: Thanks, I do know how to solve this problem using if-else. I'm new at learning C and programming in general. Can you go a little more into detail about what you explained like say it overall in easy words?

Comment: The `case` value must be a constant that is known at compile time. In your code it isn't known until run time, but `switch` uses a fixed dispatching table or some other means. You would need, say, `case 90:` and then `case 91:` etc.

Answer (score 0):

cant use switch, use if / else

```
int user_marks;
printf("Enter your obatined marks to know your grade: ")
scanf("%d", &user_marks);

if(user_marks>=90 && user_marks<=100){
    printf("Your grade is A.");
} else {
    printf("Enter valid marks.");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `case` labels must use [integer constant expressions](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/constant_expression#Integer_constant_expression). This means that the result of these expressions must be known at compile-time. However, the value of `user_marks` is not known at compile-time.

Even if `user_marks` were an integer constant, the line

```
case user_marks>=90 && user_marks<=100:
```

would still be wrong, because, depending on the value of `user_marks`, the expression `user_marks>=90 && user_marks<=100` would evaluate to either `0` (false) or `1` (true), so the entire line would be equivalent to either

```
case 0:
```

or

```
case 1:
```

which is not what you want.

Therefore, if you really wanted to use a `switch` statement, you would have to do the following instead:

```
switch (user_marks)
{
    case 90:
    case 91:
    case 92:
    case 93:
    case 94:
    case 95:
    case 96:
    case 97:
    case 98:
    case 99:
    case 100:
        printf("Your grade is A.");
        break;

    default:
        printf("Enter valid marks.");
        break;
}
```

However, it is simpler to use an `if`...`else` statement instead:

```
if ( user_marks >= 90 && user_marks <= 100 )
{
    printf( "Your grade is A." );
}
else
{
    printf( "Enter valid marks." );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When the source data is particularly well understood, a "hashing function" can be used to determine a quality of that data.

The problem stated "only 90-100" are equivalent to "A", and the desire to use a `switch()` statement.

The following tests several values in sequence, hashing them to a constant. (It's expected that values won't be greater than 100.

```
int my_main() {

    int marks[] = { 70, 85, 89, 90, 94, 100 };

    for( int i = 0; i < sizeof marks/sizeof marks[0] ; i++ ) {
        int mark = marks[i];

        // hash:
        // leading 9 or 10 plus 1 => 10 or 11
        // integer divide by 2 of result => 5
        switch( ((mark / 10) + 1) / 2 ) {
            case 5:
                printf( "%d is worth an A\n", mark );
                break;
            default:
                printf( "%d is NOT worth an A\n", mark );
                break;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Output

```
70 is NOT worth an A
85 is NOT worth an A
89 is NOT worth an A
90 is worth an A
94 is worth an A
100 is worth an A
```

A simple if/else would be easier and clearer, of course...